# PHPStorm10 запуск из боковой панели

Tags: php, phpstorm

Добрый день. Ранее на другой машине стоял PHPStorm8,открывался из боковой панели. На новой машине стоит ubuntu16.04 на которую поставил PHPStorm10, открывается только в терминале из папки bin командой `./phpstorm.sh.`

Подскажите пож как сделать чтоб PHPStorm10 открывался из боковой панели(без терминала)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот два варианта:

1. После запуска на боковой панели на значке PhpStorm нажать правой кнопкой мыши и далее `Lock to Launcher`
2. в PhpStorm в меню Tools -> Create Desktop Entry

Comment: Попробовал 2 вариант, отработал с первого раза.
Спасибо за помощь!